# MatLab: Variable assigned during function can be used in another function

Tags: matlab, function, variables

I have a function with an output q. This function will generate a matrix, A, in order to find q. Matrix A is 100x100x100, so it takes a really long time to run this code and I want to do (lots) of other calculations with the information from A without having to run that code over and over again.

Is there a way to make both q and A (q has dimensions 100x1) accessible in another function without running the original function each time?

I though about using "global" but I'm not sure how that works.

Comment: What about just outputting two variables from your function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
assignin('base', 'var1', var1)
```

To assign variable `var` in the base work-space. This will allow you to parse it to other functions and it will persist.

Alternatively you can simply return it:

```
function [other_vars var1] = theFunk(input)
```

Then to use it in other functions you can make it global:

```
global VAR_GLOBAL = var;
```

and in your function use:

```
function [stuff] = someOtherFunction(input)
    global VAR_GLOBAL
    % Do some stuff with VAR_GLOBAL
```

or simply pass it into your other functions:

```
function [stuff] = someOtherFunction(input, var1)
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that your function is doing two separate things, and needs some refactoring...

Consider [extracting](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html) the part that computes the matrix `A` into a separate function. The other function will take the produced matrix `A` as input and compute the output `q`. Otherwise known as the ["Extract Till You Drop"](https://sites.google.com/site/unclebobconsultingllc/one-thing-extract-till-you-drop) principle :)